# Gradually growing iframe onclick

Tags: javascript, iframe

im trying to make the iframe gradually grow onclick from the link(link being the center point). its going to be the size of the link then grow to the size of the iframe. there will be other links so they will have the same effect. any ideas? sorry im a newbie

```
<html>  
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function makeFrame(src) {
ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
ifrm.setAttribute("onmouseout","closeFrame()")
ifrm.setAttribute("src","");
ifrm.style.display = "block";
ifrm.style.width = "640px";
ifrm.style.height = "400px";
ifrm.style.marginLeft = "325px";
ifrm.style.marginTop = "125px";
ifrm.style.position = "absolute";
ifrm.style.top="0px";
ifrm.style.color="red";
ifrm.style.zIndex= "101";
document.body.appendChild(ifrm);

}
function closeFrame(){
ifrm.style.display = "none";
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<img src="" onclick=makeFrame() height="100px" width="100px" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: BTW - 640+"px"; - it's perfectly fine to use "640px";

Comment: Also, margins need units as well.

Answer (score 0):

you could create another function that animates the desired behavior, i.e. something that adds small increments to the height and width of your iframe.

```
<script>
function grow () {
    ifrm = document.getElementById('amazingIFrame');
    if (ifrm.style.width < 500) {
        ifrm.style.width += 10;
    } else {
        clearInterval(interval);  // stop growing when it's big enough
    }
}
function startGrow() {
    makeFrame(src); // create the frame first
    interval = setInterval("grow()", 10);  // grow every 10 ms
}
</script>
```

Then you could have

```
<img onClick="startGrow();">
```

somewhere in your document.

You might also have to adjust the position as it grows so that it stays centered, but the idea is there.

It sounds like you're trying to have a box open up when a user hovers over a link.  There are better ways of doing this than an iframe, such as a div with dynamically loaded content.

Comment: The code is a little confusing though.  The question asks about putting this behavior onMouseOver for a link, but your code has onClick for an img tag.

Comment: oh yes that my mistake i changed it it supposed to be onclick for me its not working